# MUI Table Pagination: How does going to previous page work?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm referring to this example which is from MUI's [website](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/): https://codesandbox.io/s/3sjxh?file=/demo.js:8248-8255

I don't understand how `onPageChange` is able to make both navigating to `previous` and `next` page work.

```
      <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={rows.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
```

All `handleChangePage` does is to set the new `page` value, but how does it know whether to reduce the `count` or increase it?

```
const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how does it know whether to reduce the count or increase it?

What "count"?  You may be over-thinking this.  The total count of records doesn't change.  The only thing that event handler is providing is the page number that the user clicked on.

You provide to the component key pieces of information:

```
count={rows.length}
rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
page={page}
```

The total count of rows, how many rows are on any given page, and the current page.  Based on this information the component can internally calculate (and display as UI elements for navigation) how many pages exist in total and what pages are before/after the current page.

So if the current page is `3` and there are enough records to fill 6 pages then the component can easily determine to display links for pages 1, 2, 4, 5, and 6.

When a user clicks on that link, the component invokes this `onPageChange` event and provides you with the page that the user has selected.  It doesn't matter if that page is earlier or later in the sequence of pages.  If the user clicked on page 2, you get the value `2`.  If the user clicked on page 6, you get the value `6`.  (Or maybe `1` and `5` if it's zero-indexed?)

If the component renders a link with the text "Prev" or "Next" then it's still just a link to a numeric page.  It doesn't matter what text the link has.